# Multiple SQL Queries in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display 3 tables on one page.

I'm using 3 different queries, but it’s giving me an error on the second query. I'm assuming this isn't a syntax error, but it could be. Let me know if you need any more details.

The code,

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != "YES")
{
    header("location:index.php?problem=notLoggedIn");
}
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<html>
<div style="width: 80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div style="float: right;">Welcome <? print($name); ?></div>
<?php 
//Connect to MSSQL Server
$myServer = ".\MSSQLSERVER2008";
$myUser = "admin";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "database"; 

//connection to the server
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

  //select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");  

$result = mssql_query("SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table4
ON table1.user_id=table4.user_id;");
if(!$result){
//echo 'Failed to receive data. Please try again, or contact support.';
}
else{
//echo 'Successfully received data.';
//$results = mssql_query($result);
//var_dump($results);
}
?>
<center>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Name of Center</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name_of_Center'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Contact Name</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Contact_Name'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Street Address</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Street_Address'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['State_or_Province'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <?php while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Zipcode'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Instructions</th>
        <?php while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Instructions'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result, 0); ?>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php//insert form results into database
$result2 = mssql_query("SELECT *
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table4
ON tale2.user_id=table4.user_id;");
if(!$result2){
//echo 'Failed to receive data. Please try again, or contact support.';
}
else{
//echo 'Successfully received data.';
//$results = mssql_query($result);
//var_dump($results);
}?>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name 1</th>
        <?php while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Last_Name_1'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result2, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name 1</th>
        <?php while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['First_Name_1'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result2, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Mobile Phone 1</th>
        <?php while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Mobile_Phone_1'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result2, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> 3 Work Phone</th>
        <?php while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Work_Phone_3'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result2, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>3 Email</th>
        <?php while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Email_3'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result2, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
</table>

<?php//insert form results into database
$result3 = mssql_query("SELECT *
FROM table3
INNER JOIN table4
ON table3.user_id=table4.user_id;");
if(!$result3){
//echo 'Failed to receive data. Please try again, or contact support.';
}
else{
//echo 'Successfully received data.';
//$results = mssql_query($result);
//var_dump($results);
}?>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Insured Name</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Insured_Name'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Policy Number</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Policy_Number'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Specimen Number 5</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Specimen_Number_5'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Specimen Number 6</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Specimen_Number_6'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Premium 24</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Premium_24'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <th>Premium 25</th>
        <?php while($row3 = mssql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row3['Premium_25'] . "</td>"; }
        mssql_data_seek($result3, 0); ?>    
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
<style>
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

td a:link {
 color:  white;
}

td a:visited {
 color: white;
} 

td a:active {
 color: white; 
} 
</style>

</html>
```

Here's the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

For This Line:

```
$result2 = mssql_query("SELECT *
```

Comment: Have you run this query in the database tools?

Comment: I've run the queries by themselves and they've worked. I'm having an issue with there being more than one being run on a single page.

Comment: are you sure you have (<?) php short tag enabled?

Comment: I do think that your way of populating columns is pretty convoluted, but that is for another day. Can you output any other error data? If not, can you find the error in the logs to see if it is more detailed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<?php//insert form results into database
$result3 = mssql_query("SELECT *
```

...to this:

```
<?php
//insert form results into database
$result3 = mssql_query("SELECT *
```

---

***Edit:*** There should at least be a space between `<?php` and code or a comment (after the last `p`).

In not doing so, will cause a parse error.

**Invalid:** `<?php// comment`

**Invalid:** `<?phpecho "Hello";`

As opposed to:

**Valid:** `<?php // comment`

**Valid:** `<?php echo "Hello";`

Comment: This would not solve the OP's problem or answer his question. Why is this important?

Comment: Yeah, so this totally worked. Thanks so much. -2 on this answer? So much hate on Stacksonstacksonstacksoverflow.

Comment: Actually @JayBlanchard having the `<?php// comments` will cause a parse error. Try this `<?php//comment echo "hey";` and see the result.

Comment: Ah - he said keep code away (which was done). Comments != code.

Comment: True, yet it's debatable, but it's not my battle ;-) @JayBlanchard yet it was the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the down votes! Yeah, meant to say comments instead of code, but regardless, my response was correct either way, as Fred was kind enough to point out in his edits.

Answer (score 1):

Your JOIN clause in the $result2 query includes " ON tale2.user_id=table4.user_id; " . I assume you mean table2.user_id rather than tale2.user_id? In fact, it's more than an assumption, since you're selecting from table2, not tale2. (I would have included this as a comment but don't have the reputation level yet.)

Comment: The name of the tables were just placeholders for the actual names. My bad on the typo. Thanks for pointing it out.